# Charlie Williams' bit about the Pygmie tribe

Tags: pronunciation, british-english, listening, jokes, dialect

Would somebody be so kind to translate Yorkshire into English. Suppose the comedian is popular enough that a review will be appreciated by some: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=7WucumXbAsk&t=240s (at the four minute mark).

I'm amazed I understood at least half of it after two runs up to that point ("cause he talked like that, the chief, you see"), enough to estimate the punch line, but the last punchline keeps me guessing if it is a pun about the accent itself. What is the name of the tribe (and why is it funny?).

All the fluff in the set up shouldn't matter of course. I suppose its a known joke written down somewhere so the answer could be sourcable.

Comment: The Elawi Tribe: sounds like "Where the [h]ell are we?"

Comment: @WeatherVane Thanx. You or anyone make it an answer, I'll upvote. A citation can be added later if needed.